# Cloning a DIV & amending the ID

Tags: javascript

I need to clone a styled DIV (`id="#mirrorBG1"`) and amend the new `div` id to `id="#mirrorBG2"` then apply the class `#mirrorBG2` in CSS to control the new `div` position & size etc.

Any ideas, please!

```
<div id="mirrorBG1">IMAGE#1 (*main image*) </div>

resulting in adding: <div id="mirrorBG2">IMAGE#1 (*same image*) </div>

#mirrorBG1 { width:50%; height:300px; background-color:#0F0"; float:left; clear:both; }
#mirrorBG2 { width:50%; height:300px; background-color:#FF0"; float:right; clear:both; }
```

Comment: yeah jQuery is what I see is prob my best bet. I'm just not a hardcore coder :/

Answer (score 1):

Updated version:

```
var div2 = document.getElementById("mirrorBG1").cloneNode(true);
div2.setAttribute("id","mirrorBG2");
div2.className = "mirrorBG2";
```

After that you append your div wherever you want it to.
For example:

```
document.body.insertBefore(div2, null);
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPNgQ/3/)

edit:

as stavarotti noted, classList isn't fully supported by IE versions previous to 10.

so instead of:

```
div2.classList.remove("mirrorBG1");
div2.classList.add("mirrorBG2");
```

You can do this instead:

```
div2.className = "mirrorBG2";
```

This will replace the class "mirrorBG1" with "mirrorBG2".

I updated the jsfiddle to show these changes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Could I have a full working code example please? I'm not too up on JS. I'm more of a front end designer. Thanks

Comment: Note that classList is only supported in IE10+ unless you use a shim.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't too much of a dependency for you, consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) methods. For more info see [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: Yeah read some of that, I'm not too up on JS, more of a front end designer. Thanks!